# Pivoting in Sybase ASE

Tags: sap-ase

The context of the question is based on the following

```
ID | Group_Level | Group_Values

1 | Division | Value 1
2 | Department | Value 2
3 | Class | Value 3
```

should be pivoted into

```
ID | Division | Department | Class

1 | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
2 | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
```

Based on many searches and experiments I have done trying pivoting in Sybase ASE, there seems to be only support for pivoting when you know what the values can be.

For example,

```
select id,
max (case when group_level = 'Division' then Group_Values else null end) Division,
max (case when group_level = 'Department' then Group_Values else null end) Department,
max (case when group_level = 'Class' then Group_Values else null end) Class
from YourTable group by id
```

works when we know values of group_level. All the other answers I got doesn't work in Sybase ASE and were based on Sybase Anywhere or other DB.

So, Is there a way this can be done more generic when we don't know the values of that field in Sybase-ASE

The example and answer are taken from 
[Pivoting in Sybase SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114032/pivoting-in-sybase-sql-query)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652613/sybase-sql-self-join-multiple-rows/39735610#39735610

Comment: The issue again is that he knows that there 3 columns to fill so he does a 3 way self join. The requirement here is that we don't know the number of joins we want I.e. the number of colums